# How can I detect landscape orientation in a WP7 template using SketchFlow?

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend, sketchflow

I am using the official [Windows Phone 7 SketchFlow template](http://wp7sketchflow.codeplex.com/), based on the Windows Phone SDK. Is there any way to detect when the user has clicked the landscape orientation button in the player, and act accordingly? Specifically, I'd like to display completely different views depending on orientation. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the portrait and landscape functionality is implemented with visual states. If you select the correct visual state and make your changes (such as showing different controls) it should work the way you want.

Comment: Works perfectly! To have a completely different view, you have to set the opacity of existing controls to 0. Thank you!